# different colors in one Listbox of tkinter using f string?

Tags: tkinter, colors, listbox

Is it possible to use different colors in one Listbox using f string. for example:

`user.insert(END, f' hi(in red color) how are you? (in green color)')`

Comment: Not using an f string, no. That's not what they're for. Look into `tkinter.Style()` and style `tags`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use different colors in one Listbox using f string.

No, it is not. You can't have multiple colors for a single item in a listbox. If you need to do that you'll need to use a `Text` widget, and add bindings to replicate the behavior of a listbox*. Even then, you can't embed color information in a string. You'll have to use the tag functionality in the text widget to colorize the lines as you see fit.

* Note: this will require a fair amount of work. The `Text` widget gives you all of the basic building blocks but you will have to write custom bindings for button clicks and up/down arrows and keyclicks so that they behave like a listbox.

Comment: Thanks again Bryan for your quick reply. I appreciate it. that's why people say Tkinter is not developed well and it is better to use PyQt6. but still, I like Tkinter. could you just show your comment in a code? I didn't understand well.

Comment: @Naser _"that's why people say Tkinter is not developed well"_ - I disagree. Tkinter is very well designed. It's just not designed to work the way you want it. The mechanism for adding color is part of a more robust system that lets you modify colors, fonts, spacing, and many other attributes. Tkinter even lets you stack tags so you can have multiple attributes applied to a range of text.

Comment: Hi Bryan, still waiting for your help. I really need it. I will appreciate if you show your last comment in real codes to see what you meant by Text widget and add bindings to replicate the behavior of a Listbox.

Comment: @Naser: sorry, I'm not a free coding service, what you're asking will take a fair amount of work. The concept is simple, but the implementation is somewhat tedious.

Comment: hmmm. no worries, thanks for your help on highlight text.